# Search an element in array of JSON objects in jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, object

I have an array of JSON objects where these objects may also be array of JSON objects . Now, I need to find a value in it dynamically as the no: of objects willl not be same in the array, . For example,

```json
[
  {
    "Plan": {
      "Node Type": "CTE Scan",
      "CTE Name": "tab",
      "Alias": "tab",
      "Startup Cost": 756.66,
      "Total Cost": 761.16,
      "Plan Rows": 67,
      "Plan Width": 12,
      "Filter": "(sum > 10000)",
      "Plans": [
        {
          "Node Type": "Aggregate",
          "Strategy": "Sorted",
          "Parent Relationship": "InitPlan",
          "Subplan Name": "CTE tab",
          "Startup Cost": 471.70,
          "Total Cost": 756.66,
          "Plan Rows": 200,
          "Plan Width": 8,
          "Plans": [
            {
              "Node Type": "Merge Join",
              "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
              "Join Type": "Inner",
              "Startup Cost": 471.70,
              "Total Cost": 684.82,
              "Plan Rows": 13968,
              "Plan Width": 8,
              "Merge Cond": "(p.pr_id = ep.pr_id)",
              "Plans": [
                {
                  "Node Type": "Sort",
                  "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
                  "Startup Cost": 51.37,
                  "Total Cost": 53.17,
                  "Plan Rows": 720,
                  "Plan Width": 4,
                  "Sort Key": ["p.pr_id"],
                  "Plans": [
                    {
                      "Node Type": "Seq Scan",
                      "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
                      "Relation Name": "product",
                      "Alias": "p",
                      "Startup Cost": 0.00,
                      "Total Cost": 17.20,
                      "Plan Rows": 720,
                      "Plan Width": 4
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "Node Type": "Sort",
                  "Parent Relationship": "Inner",
                  "Startup Cost": 420.33,
                  "Total Cost": 430.03,
                  "Plan Rows": 3880,
                  "Plan Width": 8,
                  "Sort Key": ["ep.pr_id"],
                  "Plans": [
                    {
                      "Node Type": "Hash Join",
                      "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
                      "Join Type": "Inner",
                      "Startup Cost": 19.00,
                      "Total Cost": 189.05,
                      "Plan Rows": 3880,
                      "Plan Width": 8,
                      "Hash Cond": "(ep.emp_id = e.emp_id)",
                      "Plans": [
                        {
                          "Node Type": "Seq Scan",
                          "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
                          "Relation Name": "employee_vs_product",
                          "Alias": "ep",
                          "Startup Cost": 0.00,
                          "Total Cost": 29.40,
                          "Plan Rows": 1940,
                          "Plan Width": 12
                        },
                        {
                          "Node Type": "Hash",
                          "Parent Relationship": "Inner",
                          "Startup Cost": 14.00,
                          "Total Cost": 14.00,
                          "Plan Rows": 400,
                          "Plan Width": 12,
                          "Plans": [
                            {
                              "Node Type": "Seq Scan",
                              "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
                              "Relation Name": "employee",
                              "Alias": "e",
                              "Startup Cost": 0.00,
                              "Total Cost": 14.00,
                              "Plan Rows": 400,
                              "Plan Width": 12
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Here, I need to find the values with key "Relaion Name"...There are three values with that key and we do not know no: of objects that are present in it..so I need a solution to find the values with that key  dynamically.

I tried to code a recursive function but I am not successful..so help me if you know it.

Recursive function I tried:

```js
var result1=searchInPlan(jsonarray[0].Plan);
function searchInPlan(node)
{
 var result='';
 {
  if(node.Plans == undefined)
  {
   if(node["Relation Type"] != undefined)
    result +=  node["Relation Name"];
   return result;
  }
  else
  {
   return result+searchInPlans(node.Plans);
  }
 }
}

function searchInPlans(nodes)
{
 console.log("bollo",nodes);
 var result = '';
 for(j=0;j<nodes.length;j++)
 {
  result += searchInPlan(nodes[j]);
 }
 return result;
}
```

It is working but I am able to get only the first value with that key...I need all the values with that key..help me..

Comment: use the `underscore` library, it's like `linq` for `javascript`

Comment: share the recursive function that you have tried... people will be more willing to respond and they may also suggest alternatives.

Comment: @JoelGregory...I added the Recursive function I tried..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the working code for my problem...

```js
var x=[];
var y=[];
var i1=0;
var j1=0;
function scan(obj) {
    var k;
    if (obj instanceof Object) {
        for (k in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                if(k == "Relation Name")
    {
     x[i1]= obj[k];
     i1++;
     
    }
                scan(obj[k]);
            }
        }
    }

};
```